# Hide parent div if :empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to hide a parent div if a sibling is empty when document is ready. Doesn't seem to work for me:

```js
$('.pp-post-content-location:empty').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="pp-post-content-subtitle">Location</span>
  <div class="pp-post-content-location"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet and it works absolutely fine. Could you check your console for errors and let us know if there is any. Also, make sure you're running your code in a document.ready event handler

Comment: yes it is working fine. what do u expect?

Comment: Well that's weird. The <span> content still shows up on my screen. It is in a document.ready and I don't get any errors in the console. It's in a wordpress site not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Is your browser up to date?

Comment: it is working fine.

Comment: using the latest google chrome

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with WordPress or my theme that is causing this. But I got some other JQuery that is running fine just not this.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

First of All You Haven't included Document .ready in your Script

Here's The Code Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var text=$('.pp-post-content-location').text(); //text Is Jquery Function which gets the content inside a element

if(text==""){  
$('.pp-post-content-location').parent().hide();
}
});
```

Then Just a Simple If Condition to check That is there any Content In Specified Element If it has not Any content then it will hide the PARENT element